# How to use crystal report in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

Help!

I have a software that needs to print data and i want to use crystal report so that i could have multiple pages. I've tried using the crystal report and when you're using crystal report you need to export the database and its tables. But the problem is that I've coded my software that when it runs for the first time it will create a specific database and its corresponding tables. how can i use crystal report without exporting the database? I've already downloaded the crystal report. please help me.

Comment: You could set the DataSource of your report to a dataset instead of to a database.

Comment: I have no idea where you got the idea that you have to export a database to use crystal reports, but you don't want to use crystal reports anyway. Crystal Reports the application is a great tool, but reports in .NET apps is a mess. Please at least consider Microsoft reports (.rdlc)

Comment: @Steve how can i do that? how can i set the datasource to a dataset? please help me..

Comment: `[Report].DataSource = DS`